# Dagger2 Field Injection not working

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am familiar with Spring dependency injection, but Dagger2 is new to me. I am trying to get a simple java application working but field injection does not work.

I have a class `Main`, that depends on a class `MainBusiness` which in turn depends on `MainDao`.

`MainBusiness` gets injected into `Main` fine, but `MainDao` does not get injected into `MainBusiness` and throws a `NullPointerException`.

Here is the `MainDao` that implements an `interface` `IMainDao`

```
public class MainDao implements IMainDao
{       
    @Inject
    public MainDao()
    {
    }

    public String getResource()
    {
        return "This is the resource you are looking for";
    }
}
```

Here is the `MainBusiness` that implements `IMainBusiness`

```
public class MainBusiness implements IMainBusiness
{
    // package friendly field.  
    @Inject
    IMainDao mainDao;

    @Inject
    public MainBusiness()
    {
    }

    public String getResource()
    {       
        return mainDao.getResource(); // throws NPE here.
    }

}
```

Here is the `AppModule`

```
@Module
public class AppModule
{   
    /**
     * Provides a singleton instance of the MainDao 
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public IMainDao providesMainDao()
    {
        return new MainDao();
    }

    /**
     * Provides a singleton instance of the MainBusiness Class
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public IMainBusiness providesMainBusiness()
    {
        return new MainBusiness();
    }
}
```

The `AppComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent
{

    /**
     * @param main
     */
    void inject(Main main); 
}
```

And the `Main` class

```
public class Main
{   
    @Inject
    IMainBusiness mainBusiness;

    public Main()
    {
        AppComponent dac = DaggerAppComponent.builder().build();        
        dac.inject(this);       
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Main main = new Main();     
        System.out.println(main.mainBusiness.getResource());
    }
}
```

It throws an NPE on `MainBusiness.getResource(MainBusiness.java:14)`

What am I missing here? Appreciate any help I can get.

**P.S This is a plain `Java` application. It is not an `Android` application.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Field injection will inject the fields of the object you pass in. `someComponent.inject(someObject)` will then inject the fields of `someObject`, but it does not inject the dependencies transitively. Hence `MainBusiness` will still have an uninitialized DAO.

If you call `new MainBusiness();` yourself you can't expect Dagger to take care of it. You should use constructor injection, and not call `new` yourself. Modules are for bindings, or additional setup, and should reduce the boilerplate of calling all the constructors yourself.

I took some liberty to switch to constructor injection and completely remove field injection, since it is not needed for your use case. (Maybe there's some typo, I did not compile it)

```
@Singleton
public class MainDao implements IMainDao
{       
    @Inject
    public MainDao()
    {
    }
}

@Singleton
public class MainBusiness implements IMainBusiness
{
    private IMainDao mainDao;

    @Inject
    public MainBusiness(IMainDao mainDao)
    {
        this.mainDao = mainDao;
    }
}

@Module
interface AppModule {

    @Binds IMainBusiness bindBusiness(MainBusiness impl);

    @Binds IMainDao bindDao(MainDao impl);

}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent
{
    //  -> no reason not to use constructor injection here as well
    Main getMain(); // provision method
}

public class Main
{   

    private IMainBusiness mainBusiness;

    // favor constructor injection
    @Inject
    public Main(IMainBusiness mainBusiness)
    {
        this.mainBusiness = mainBusiness;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        AppComponent component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().build()
        Main main = component.getMain();
        System.out.println(main.mainBusiness.getResource());
    }
}
```

I suggest that you have another look at some guides to make sure you understand the concepts, or you might be creating more work for yourself than necessary. I also wrote a post recently where I try to [clear up some misconceptions about Dagger](https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2017/11/11/dagger-rules-engagement.html).

Comment: So constructor injection is the way to go. Will keep that in mind. Good blog by the way.