# Can I use Dagger 2's field injection in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I posted a question ([Dagger 2 does not generate the component class (Android, Kotlin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247696/dagger-2-does-not-generate-the-component-class-android-kotlin)), and after some experiments, it seems that the problem might be due to that Kotlin hides the field.

```
class CoffeeShop {
    @Inject
    var theCoffee: Coffee? = null
}
```

The error message is,

```
:app:kaptDebugKotline: ...\CoffeeShop.java:7:
error: Dagger does not support injection into private fields
e:     private ....Coffee theCoffee;
```

`theCoffee` was not private in my source code. But I think Kotlin may be translating

```
class CoffeeShop {
    @Inject
    var theCoffee: Coffee? = null
}
```

into Java code of

```
class CoffeeShop {
    @Inject
    private Coffee theCoffee = null;
    public Coffee getTheCoffee();
    public void setTheCoffee();
}
```

Can I use field injection in Kotlin?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> I think Kotlin may be translating [...] into Java code of [...]

And you would be correct, that's exactly what happens.

Typically in Kotlin you wouldn't write

```
@Inject var coffee: Coffee? = null
```

because when you're going to access coffee, it will never be null. In other words you will always inject the object before accessing it's fields. That makes the operators `!!` redundant and `?` unnecessary. Kotlin has `lateinit` property modifier to express this.

```
@Inject lateinit var coffee: Coffee
```

When you use `lateinit` the generated field has the same visibility as its getter and setter, in this case `public`. This makes it work with Dagger.

You can see the result by viewing generated Kotlin bytecode.

> Main menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode

However, even better approach would be injecting the class constructor:

```
class CoffeeShop @Inject constructor(val coffee: Coffee) {
    //...
}
```

In this case `coffee` is not `var` and can't be reassigned.

Injecting constructor is not an option when the instance is created for you by a framework, Android activity is a good example.

---

**Note:** When using qualifiers you have to specify `field` annotation target on them:

```
@Inject @field:Named("Arabica") @field:Arabica
lateinit var coffee: Coffee
```

**Edit:** You don't need to add the `field` target when using [Dagger 2.25 or newer](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.25.2).

---

> Can I use field injection in Kotlin?

Yes you can. As explained above, field injection is actually applied for `lateinit` properties.

But you were probably interested in generating and injecting fields without getter/setter in Kotlin.

```
@JvmField @Inject
var coffee: Coffee? = null
```

Comment: Actually I saw `lateinit` before posting this question, but if I use 'lateinit', it seemed that I could no longer use field injection but had to use constructor injection, is that correct? The error message was `Coffee cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.`. So, doesn't that make the answer to my question a "no"?

Comment: @DamnVegetables Damn, I completely missed the question :D Check out the updated answer. `but if I use 'lateinit', it seemed that I could no longer use field injection but had to use constructor injection` Now I'm not sure what you mean by `field injection`. Calling `MembersInjector` manually? That works with lateinit. lateinit=field as far as dagger is concerned.

Comment: Thank you. If you do not mind, where does `Arabica` came from? And the error message, `@Provides- or @Produces-annotated method`, does that mean a provide/produces for `CoffeeShop`? Because a provide method for `Coffee` already exists. (The full source is in the question I mentioned.)

Comment: @DamnVegetables `Arabica` is a made up [custom qualifier](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#qualifiers). You probably won't need qualifiers just now. Focus on getting it to work. About the error: Dagger needs to inject `val coffee: Coffee` and  for that it needs to know where `Coffee` comes from. As the error hints there are two ways. The [user guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html) explains it best, I think.