# UninitializedPropertyAccessException using dagger 2

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

> I am trying to inject an **AlertDialog** to **MainActivity** like

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject
    val alertStore:AlertStore;  //propery must be initialized or abstract Error

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Where as **AppComponent.kt**

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class
    ]
)
@Singleton
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        fun addContext(@BindsInstance context: Context): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**AppModule.kt**

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAlertStore(context: Context) : AlertStore = AlertStore(context)
}
```

**App.kt**

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().addContext(this).build()
    }
}
```

I am new to dagger. So bear with me. I Think I am missing context . Suggest me and please explain a little bit So I understand this concept as well

Do I have to inject MainActivity as well to get Alert or my context is missing.

**File Under build folder Generated**

```
@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 15}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000&\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\u0012\u0010\t\u001a\u00020\n2\b\u0010\u000b\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\fH\u0014R\u0016\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u00048\u0006X\u0087\u0004\u00a2\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0005\u0010\u0006R\u000e\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\bX\u0082.\u00a2\u0006\u0002\n\u0000\u00a8\u0006\r"}, d2 = {"Lcom/example/myapplication/MainActivity;", "Lcom/example/myapplication/common/BaseActivity;", "()V", "alertStore", "Lcom/example/myapplication/common/AlertStore;", "getAlertStore", "()Lcom/example/myapplication/common/AlertStore;", "viewModel", "Lcom/example/myapplication/home/MainViewModel;", "onCreate", "", "savedInstanceState", "Landroid/os/Bundle;", "app_debug"})
public final class MainActivity extends com.example.myapplication.common.BaseActivity {
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @javax.inject.Inject()
    private final com.example.myapplication.common.AlertStore alertStore = null;
    private com.example.myapplication.home.MainViewModel viewModel;
    private java.util.HashMap _$_findViewCache;

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final com.example.myapplication.common.AlertStore getAlertStore() {
        return null;
    }

    @java.lang.Override()
    protected void onCreate(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    public MainActivity() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**EDIT after Alexey Suggestion**

After updating my variable like

```
@Inject lateinit var alertStore: AlertStore
```

The error gone but on running app below error occur

> Method threw **'kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException'** exception.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248478/can-i-use-dagger-2s-field-injection-in-kotlin.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov see my Edited question  plz

Comment: Here's a simple dagger setup https://stackoverflow.com/a/58009976/2235972

Comment: You didn't call `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` before `super.onCreate`...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you are right. I made two mistake ,First I didn't add ActivityModule and secondly I didn't call AndroidInjection.inject(this). How could I get rid of calling this. Is there a technique or an annotation which inject it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not directly related to *Dagger*, but rather to *Kotlin*.

Sinc you use a `val` property, you need to initialize it with a value. Otherwise it would be uninitialized while the contract states that it's non-null. An abstract property obviously wouldn't work, so you might need to declare you property differently and inject with a setter.

```
@set:Inject internal lateinit var alertStore: AlertStore
```

Comment: tynn I have tried your solution along with @AlexeyRomanov but now UnintializedPropertyAccessException occur. Plz tell me how to pass context to AlertStore in AppModule.kt

Comment: Have you created an `ActivityModule`?

Comment: No , Do I have to inject Activity as well ? Why? And from where AlertStore get Context to be initialized??

Comment: This exceeds the scope of this question. Try to google some tutorials. This article seems like a good start https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe