# Field injection in kotlin is always null

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to do a field injection in a non Activity class, but I am always getting that the field has not been initialized/null. I have read [Can I use Dagger 2's field injection in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248478/can-i-use-dagger-2s-field-injection-in-kotlin), also [Dagger 2 on Android @Singleton annotated class not being injected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417795/dagger-2-on-android-singleton-annotated-class-not-being-injected), and still have the same problem. Here is how I have setted it up

This is the model class

```
class Greetings {
    val sayHello: String = "Hello from Dagger 2" 
}
```

This is the module class

```
@Module
class GreetingsModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesGreetings(): Greetings {
        return Greetings()
    }
}
```

This is the component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(GreetingsModule::class))
interface GreetingsComponent {
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
    fun inject(testGreetings: TestGreetings)
}
```

And the class that extends from Application

```
class App: Application() {
    private lateinit var greetingsComponent: GreetingsComponent
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        greetingsComponent = DaggerGreetingsComponent.builder().build()
    }
    fun getGreetings() = greetingsComponent
}
```

And this is how I am injecting it into another class and where is null/not initialized

```
class TestGreetings {
    @Inject
    lateinit var greetings: Greetings
    fun checkIfNull() {
        if  (greetings != null) {
            Log.d("INFO", "${ greetings.sayHello}")
        } else {
            Log.d("INFO", "null !!!!!!")

        }
    }
}
```

What exactly I am doing wrong??

Comment: how you inject it in activity?

Comment: how do you inject `TestGreetings`? can you show the code for that part?

Comment: I thought that by adding the inject methond on the component was enough, check the GreetingsComponent interface, do I need something else?

Comment: I mean the usage of `fun inject(testGreetings: TestGreetings)`. Can you show where do you use this?

Comment: @FranzAndel thxs a lot for your time, I really appreciate this. Currently I am not using this method, can you please tell me please how and where should I call it? I am trying to learn dagger, but apparently is harder than I thought. I cant call it like I did on the MainActivity,  which I did like this  (application as App).getGreetings().inject(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I'll try to answer

You can't use Field Injection which is `Greetings` in `TestGreetings` class because Dagger doesn't know how to inject it.

Field Injection is usually used, for components that is related to Android Framework, so in your case is `MainActivity`

`TestGreetings` class is not Android Framework class, so it is better to use Constructor Injection, like this

```
class TestGreetings(private val greetings: Greetings) {

    fun checkIfNull() {
        if  (greetings != null) {
            Log.d("INFO", "${ greetings.sayHello}")
        } else {
            Log.d("INFO", "null !!!!!!")

        }
    }
}
```

In order for Dagger to know how to initialize `TestGreetings` class, you need to define it in `GreetingsModule` class

```
@Module
class GreetingsModule {
    ...
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesTestGreetings(greetings: Greetings): TestGreetings {
        return TestGreetings(greetings)
    }
}
```

Now you can use `TestGreetings` class in `MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
   @Inject
   lateinit var testGreetings: TestGreetings
   
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       ...
       testGreetings.checkIfNull()
   }
}
```

Lastly, you can remove `fun inject(testGreetings: TestGreetings)` in `GreetingsComponent`

P.s. Make sure your Dagger setup in `MainActivity` is correct

Hopefully this clear the things out :)

Comment: sure, no problem :)